# If a seimigroup's left identity is unique, can it be two-side identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If a seimigroup's left identity is unique, can it be two-side identity?

The answer is true if we talk it in a ring. Like construct $(be-b+e)a=a$. But in a semigroup I can't image how to construct a equation so we can use the condition uniqueness. So I am wondeting if the statement is false. But I also couldn't get a counterexample.

Comment: I think you mean '*must it be* (two-sided) identity'?

Comment: yes，i should specified it

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting question.
Let $S=${$x,y$} (where $x$ is not equal with $y$). $S$ with the following operation is a semigroup:
$xy=y ,xx=y, yx=y, yy=y$.
We see that $y$ is the unique left identity of $S$, but $y$ is not an identity, other wise we have $yx=x$ then we have $x=y$.

Comment: I guess you want $yx=x$ so that $y$ is left identity, and $xy=y$ prevents it being identity.

Comment: Be careful when define such an operation, we need check if it satisfies associative.

Comment: exactly....this operation is associative

Comment: Also $S$ with that operation I defined is a semi group\

Comment: yes, having all binary products equal to $y$ is indeed associative, which is equivalent to saying it is a semigroup. However, here neither $x$ nor $y$ is a left identity. For that, we would need $yx=x$ [or $xx=x$, respectively].

Comment: Yes. thank you,your comment is true....now change $yx=y$ with $yx=x$.Then the problem is solve by this changing

Answer (score 0):

Consider a semigroup $S$ of words on letters $e, x$ of the form $x^n$ for $n>0 $ and $x^ne$ for $n\ge0$, defining
$$x^ne\cdot x^m:=x^{n+m}\quad\quad(n\ge0, m>0)\\
x^ne\cdot x^me:=x^{n+m}e\quad\qquad(n,m\ge0)$$
Here $e$ is the unique left identity, but it's not right identity as $xe\ne x$. 
Basically, $S$ is the quotient of the free semigroup of words on letters $e,x$, by the relations $ex\sim x,\ e^2\sim e$.